# How to get an expiration date in access?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to add together a query column of dates and months in access to get an expiration date. I have tried the DateAdd function and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you're trying to use, and the results of what you've tried?

Comment: I have one column of dates that are either null or XX/XX/XXX structure and another column of numbers that are months. I have tried DateAdd("m",[months],[dates]) and IIf([dates]=0,"No Date",DateAdd("m",[months],[dates])) and when I run the query it just pulls up error

Answer (score 1):

*DateAdd* doesn't accept *Null*, and you can't mix text and dates, so try with:

```
IIf([dates] Is Null,"No Date", Format(DateAdd("m",[months],Nz([dates],Date()), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
```